# Gnome 3 Shell - Launcher displayed in center of the screen

Tags: gnome, launcher

I have had this issue with Ubuntu 13.10 and now 14.04 LTS.  When I first boot up, everything is good, but after a while, the Gnome 3 launcher is displayed in the center of the screen when I display "activities".

I have not been able to determined what causes this bug to appear because, again, it does not happen at first after startup.

Has anyone else seen this?  Any suggestion on fixes?

[image: Gnome 3 Launcher displayed in center of the screen]

Comment: as you say - its probably a bug and should be reported on launchpad.  The devs may have seen this already and can advise better.

Comment: @fossfreedom That is where I was planning on going next.  I thought I would try here first.

Comment: This is https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1318561